# How to create login form with remember me using Shared Preferences in android

Tags: android

I don't know how to perform please help me?
I have tried to implement but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question more clear to us.

Comment: there are lot of examples just searh before asking

Comment: I have seen but i am not able to do it.

Comment: please follow the faqs on how to ask...

Comment: check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30591165/1921263 @MustafaBharatwala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sharepreference to set two property 
1,IsRemmerbered 
2,Name, Password

in your check event , you need to put the select state to the sharepreference, and decide whether put the name, password into it,

when you login next time, you can get the information from sharepreference

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you to maintain multiple login entry by using shared preference

**Example:**

This can store your data into the shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences prefe = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefmain", MODE_PRIVATE);

                                              int counter = prefe.getInt("historynumber", 0);

    String count = String.valueOf(counter);
                                                      SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(count, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                                      editor.putString("Name", ed_name.getText().toString());
                                                      editor.putString("Email", ed_email.getText().toString());
                                                      editor.putString("Password", ed_pass.getText().toString());
                                                      editor.commit();
                                                      counter = counter + 1;

                                                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefe.edit();
                                                      editor1.putInt("historynumber", counter);
                                                      editor1.commit();


                                                      Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Data Saved SuccessFully", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                      View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                                                      TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                                      textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                                      snackbar.show();

                                                      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                      startActivity(i);
                                                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is use for retrieving the stored data from the shared preference file in another activity for login,etc.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed_email, ed_pass;
    Button btn_submit;
    ArrayList<LogData> logindata;

    Boolean bit = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ed_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_login_email);
        ed_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_login_pass);
        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_submit);

        logindata = new ArrayList<LogData>();

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ed_email.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    ed_email.setError("Please enter the email address");
                    ed_email.requestFocus();
                    bit = false;
                }
                if (ed_pass.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    ed_pass.setError("Please enter the password");
                    ed_pass.requestFocus();
                    bit = false;
                }

                SharedPreferences prefe = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefmain", MODE_PRIVATE);

                int s = prefe.getInt("historynumber", 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    String count = String.valueOf(i);

                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(count, MODE_PRIVATE);

                    String name = pref.getString("Name", null);
                    String email = pref.getString("Email", null);
                    String pass = pref.getString("Password", null);

                    LogData ld = new LogData(name, email, pass);
                    logindata.add(ld);

                }
                if (bit == true) {

                    for (LogData lgd : logindata) {
//                    Log.i("hello", lgd.name + "" + lgd.email + "" + lgd.pass);
                        if (!(ed_email.getText().toString().equals(lgd.email) && ed_pass.getText().toString().equals(lgd.pass))) {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Username or Password is not valid", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            snackbar.show();

                        }
                        if ((ed_email.getText().toString().equals(lgd.email) && ed_pass.getText().toString().equals(lgd.pass))) {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Welcome " + lgd.name + "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            snackbar.show();
                            Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            finish();

                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class LogData {
    String name, email, pass;

    public LogData(String name, String email, String pass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```

May this helps you to maintain multiple entry of signup by using shared preference.